# Searching Directories and Removing Folders and Files in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that goes into a `components/` and runs the following command:

`cp -R vendor/* .`

I then have a second command that traverses any folder, accept the vendor folder , inside the components directory lookinf got `.git/`, '.gitignore' and `Documentation/` and removes them. How ever:

- I don't thinks it's recursive
- It doesn't actually remove those files and directories either because of the top point or because of permissions (should I add a sudo)?

A directory copied from vendor might look like:

```
something/
    child-directory/
        .git/ // -- Should be removed.
```

The command in question is:

```
  find -name vendor -prune -o \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -prune -exec rm -     rf "{}" \; 2> /dev/null || true
```

Now if it is a permission error, I wont know about it because I want it to ignore any errors and continue with the script.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the option `-prune`. Anyways, this might work for you...

```
find vendor -name '.git' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'Documentation' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It deletes everything that I tell it too in vendor when it should be ignoring vendor.